# Tkinter problems on Python 3.8 CODE no executing properly

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello guys Im learning on my own and I tried this and fix all the problems that the IDE showed, so far there is nothing bad according to the IDE but when a RUN the CODE the window is not showing up(Tkinter) I dont know what I´m doing wrong
thanks in advance

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk

class HelloView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.name = tk.StringVar()
        self.hello_string = tk.StringVar()
        self.hello_string.set("Hello World")
        name_label =ttk.Label(self, text="Name: ")
        name_entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.name)
        ch_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Change", command=self.on_change)
        hello_label = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.hello_string, font=("TkDefaultFont", 64), wraplength=600)
        name_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
        name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
        ch_button.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.E)
        hello_label.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)
        self.columnconfgure(1, weight=1)
    
    def on_change(self):
        if self.name.get().strip():
            self.hello_string.set("Hello " + self.name.get())
        else:
            self.hello_string.set("Hello World")



helo

class MyApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Hello Tkinter")
        self.geometry("800x600")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        HelloView(self).grid(sticky=(tk.E + tk.W + tk.N +tk.S))
        self.columnconfgure(0, weight=1)
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            app=MyApplication()
            app.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is that "helo" in the middle of your code ?

Comment: I copied from the notes but it is not in the IDE